# Python: getting a reference to a function from inside itself

Tags: python, function, self-reference

If I define a function:

```
def f(x):
    return x+3
```

I can later store objects as attributes of the function, like so:

```
f.thing="hello!"
```

I would like to do this from inside the code of the function itself. Problem is, how do I get a reference to the function from inside itself?

Comment: Why do you need this?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109289/how-can-python-function-access-its-own-attributes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The same way, just use its name.

```
>>> def g(x):
...   g.r = 4
...
>>> g
<function g at 0x0100AD68>
>>> g(3)
>>> g.r
4
```

Comment: I was confused by the output formatting, but recognized the code and answer is solid (+1).  This is what the "usual" Python REPL shows, and should be more recognizable for more people.  What interpreter did you use?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to do memoization, you can use a dictionary as a default parameter:

```
def f(x, memo={}):
  if x not in memo:
    memo[x] = x + 3
  return memo[x]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use a closure:

```
def gen_f():
    memo = dict()
    def f(x):
        try:
            return memo[x]
        except KeyError:
            memo[x] = x + 3
    return f
f = gen_f()
f(123)
```

Somewhat nicer IMHO