# How can a function access its own attributes?

Tags: python, function, scope, closures, attributes

**is it possible to access the python function object attributes from within the function scope?**

e.g. let's have

```
def f():
    return SOMETHING

f._x = "foo"
f()           # -> "foo"
```

now, what SOMETHING has to be, if we want to have the _x attribute content "foo" returned? if it's even possible (simply)

thanks

**UPDATE:**

i'd like the following work also:

```
g = f
del f
g()          # -> "foo"
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Statement that it is not possible (if it is the case), and why, is more satisfying than providing a way how to fake it e.g. with a different object than a function

Comment: What prevents you from simply having a function with one parameter?

Comment: Space_C0wb0y: function parameters are off topic, this is a question on theory, not the real-life pragmatic solutions

Comment: +1 for making me explore (and learn in) that corner of python internals ;-)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852401/python-getting-a-reference-to-a-function-from-inside-itself

Answer (score 60, accepted):

### Solution

Make one of the function's default arguments be a reference to the function itself.

```
def f(self):
    return self.x
f.func_defaults = (f,)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> f.x = 17
>>> b = f
>>> del f
>>> b()
17
```

### Explanation

The original poster wanted a solution that does not require a global name lookup.  The simple solution

```
def f():
    return f.x
```

performs a lookup of the global variable `f` on each call, which does not meet the requirements.  If `f` is deleted, then the function fails.  The more complicated `inspect` proposal fails in the same way.

What we want is to perform *early binding* and store the bound reference within the object itself.  The following is conceptually what we are doing:

```
def f(self=f):
    return self.x
```

In the above, `self` is a local variable, so no global lookup is performed.  However, we can't write the code as-is, because `f` is not yet defined when we try to bind the default value of `self` to it.  Instead, we set the default value after `f` is defined.

### Decorator

Here's a simple decorator to do this for you.  Note that the `self` argument must come last, unlike methods, where `self` comes first.  This also means that you must give a default value if any of your other arguments take a default value.

```
def self_reference(f):
    f.func_defaults = f.func_defaults[:-1] + (f,)
    return f

@self_reference
def foo(verb, adverb='swiftly', self=None):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.subject, verb, adverb)
```

Example:

```
>>> foo.subject = 'Fred'
>>> bar = foo
>>> del foo
>>> bar('runs')
'Fred runs swiftly'
```

Comment: This feels like a closure decorator. I like it.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this approach but cannot explain why.  For other approaches see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26631386/1322401) to ["Static variable in python?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630821/static-variable-in-python).

Comment: Can we add that `f.func_defaults` got renamed to `f.__defaults__` in Python 3 for consistency? Also the [doubts are shared by others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784840/are-you-allowed-to-modify-func-defaults-defaults-in-python-3-x-in-python)

Comment: @Steven, I don't like the decorator because in my little brain I cannot remember that this decorator must not be applied to arbitrary functions but only to those that have a predisposition to accept `self` as last argument. Guess I'll have to do the usually wrapping to get another closure

Answer (score 28):

You could just use a class to do this

```
>>> class F(object):
...     def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
...         return self._x
... 
>>> f=F()
>>> f._x = "foo"
>>> f()
'foo'
>>> g=f
>>> del f
>>> g()
'foo'
```

Comment: this is what i'd use in real scenario

Answer (score 17):

Well, let's look at what function is:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return x
... 
>>> foo.x = 777
>>> foo.x
777
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<interactive input>", line 2, in foo
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
>>> dir(foo)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__get__', 
'__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', 
'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 
'func_globals', 'func_name', 'x']
>>> getattr(foo, 'x')
777
```

Aha! So the attribute was added to the function object but it won't see it because it is looking for global `x` instead.

We can try to grab the frame of the function execution and try to look what's there (essentially what Anthony Kong suggested but w/o `inspect` module):

```
>>> def foo():
...     import sys
...     return sys._getframe()
... 
>>> fr = foo()
>>> dir(fr)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', 'f_back', 'f_builtins', 'f_code', 'f_exc_traceback', 'f_exc_type', 'f_exc_value', 'f_globals', 'f_lasti', 'f_lineno', 'f_locals', 'f_restricted', 'f_trace']
>>> fr.f_locals
{'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>}
>>> fr.f_code
<code object foo at 01753020, file "<interactive input>", line 1>
>>> fr.f_code.co_code
'd\x01\x00d\x00\x00k\x00\x00}\x00\x00|\x00\x00i\x01\x00\x83\x00\x00S'
>>> fr.f_code.co_name
'foo'
```

Aha! So maybe we can get the name of the function from the name of the code block and then look in round-about way for the attribute? Sure enough:

```
>>> getattr(fr.f_globals[fr.f_code.co_name], 'x')
777
>>> fr.f_globals[fr.f_code.co_name].x
777
>>> def foo():
...     import sys
...     frm = sys._getframe()
...     return frm.f_globals[frm.f_code.co_name].x
... 
>>> foo.x=777
>>> foo()
777
```

That's great! But would it stand the renaming and deletion of original function?

```
>>> g = foo
>>> g.func_name
'foo'
>>> g.func_code.co_name
'foo'
```

Ah, very doubtful. The function object and its code object still insist they are called `foo`. Sure enough, here is where it breaks:

```
>>> g.x
777
>>> g.x=888
>>> foo.x
888
>>> g()
888
>>> del foo
>>> g()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<interactive input>", line 4, in foo
KeyError: 'foo'
```

Dang! So in general it can't be done through introspection via the execution frames. The problems seems to be that there is a difference between *function object* and *code object* - code objects are what is executed and is just one attribute `func_code` of the function-object and as such has no access to the `func_dict` attribute, where our attribute `x` is:

```
>>> g
<function foo at 0x0173AE30>
>>> type(g)
<type 'function'>
>>> g.func_code
<code object foo at 017532F0, file "<interactive input>", line 1>
>>> type(g.func_code)
<type 'code'>
>>> g.func_dict
{'x': 888}
```

There is of course other chicanery you can do so that it seems as function - in particular the trick with class definition... but that is not a function per se. It all depends on what do you really need to do with that.

Comment: Useless as an immediate answer, but incredibly illuminating in all other ways. Really taught me a lot about the whys of scope. +1

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround you could use a factory function to fix your scope:

```
def factory():
    def inner():
        print inner.x
    return inner


>>> foo=factory()
>>> foo.x=11
>>> foo()
11
>>> bar = foo
>>> del foo
>>> bar()
11
```

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this is the *best* way to accomplish this, but you can access the attributes by using the method's name within the method:

```
>>> def foo():
...   print foo.x
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'
>>> foo.x = 5
>>> foo()
5
```

Comment: hmm. but what if i can have it working for also "renamed" function, like: `g = f; del f; print(g())`? :)

Comment: @mykhal it will preserve `x` value of course, since `g` is just another reference to something initially referenced only by `f`

Comment: nailxx: err, yes, but since we reference this with explicit function name, which is now deleted, NameError is raised

Answer (score 4):

Here's a decorator that injects current_fun into the functions globals before executing the function. It's quite the hack, but also quite effective.

```
from functools import wraps


def introspective(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        exists = 'current_fun' in f.func_globals
        old = f.func_globals.get('current_fun',None)
        f.func_globals['current_fun'] = wrapper
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            if exists:
                f.func_globals['current_fun'] = old
            else:
                del f.func_globals['current_fun']
    return wrapper

@introspective
def f():
    print 'func_dict is ',current_fun.func_dict
    print '__dict__ is ',current_fun.__dict__
    print 'x is ',current_fun.x
```

Here's a usage example

```
In [41]: f.x = 'x'

In [42]: f()
func_dict is  {'x': 'x'}
__dict__ is  {'x': 'x'}
x is  x

In [43]: g = f

In [44]: del f

In [45]: g()
func_dict is  {'x': 'x'}
__dict__ is  {'x': 'x'}
x is  x
```

Comment: Nice! :) For Python 3 `func_globals` must be replaced with `__globals__`. I have extended the decorator to accept the name for the attribute: `def introspective(f, attribute_name='self'):` and actually renamed it to `@add_self`. All `'current_fun'` occurrences must be replaced with `attribute_name`. By default the decorator wraps the attribute `self` into the function. Now I can do `self.x` inside functions and classes. I never use it _but_ for `self.logger.info()` which can now be nicely added to all of functions, methods, and classes with decorators.

Comment: Very very nice. +1

Answer (score 3):

The answer is rather simple. Just use the fact name is looked for at execution time, not compile time:

```
def f():
    return f._x

f._x = "foo"
f()           # -> "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be totally independent of the function name, you need some frame magic. For example:

```
def f2():
    import inspect
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    fname = frame.f_code.co_name
    fobj = frame.f_globals[fname]
    print fobj._x


f2._x = 2
f2()
```

Comment: interesting. looked promising, but unfortunately doesn't work well.. try `f3=f2; del f2; f3()`

Comment: i thought `inspect` requires the source file to be available?

Comment: This does not offer any improvement over the simple `return f2._x`.  The code's `co_name` is the name of the function when it was defined, so if the function is renamed, the lookup in the global dictionary will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a bit of a hackish approach, but it's possibly the most correct so far given that it works with the `g()` call as well.  It works because it's relying on whatever bytecode inspection is performed by the [dis](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/dis.html#module-dis) module, as a shortcut.

It looks more hackish than it really is partly because the `dis.disassemble()` call prints to stdout, so I redirect that into a StringIO.  I use `disassemble()` for its feature of highlighting the last instruction (add a `print text` line in there to see how it looks) and that makes it easier to grab the previous `LOAD_NAME` and the variable it used.

It would be possible to use a cleaner bytecode inspection library to do this without using the `dis` module at all, but this proves that it's possible.  This might not be the most robust approach, but then again maybe it will work in most cases.  I haven't spent enough time poking into Python internals or bytecode to know whether most `CALL_FUNCTION` bytecodes are preceded immediately by instructions that the regex trick would pick out.

```
import inspect
import dis
import re
import sys
import StringIO

def f():
    caller = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
    dis.disassemble(caller.f_code, caller.f_lasti)
    text = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    match = re.search(r'LOAD_NAME.*\((.*?)\)\s+-->', text)
    name = match.group(1)
    try:
        func = caller.f_locals[name]
    except KeyError:
        func = caller.f_globals[name]
    return func._x

f._x = 'foo'
print 'call f():', f()
g = f
del f
print 'call g():', g()
```

This generates the following output:

```
call f(): foo
call g(): foo
```

Comment: i hoped for simpler solution, but only yours fulfills the question conditions, so i'm giving you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks @mykhal.  It could likely be simplified with one of the libraries at http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=bytecode&submit=search but it really does appear that the design of Python makes this information practically unreachable.  The function object holds context for invoking the code object, but once inside you have only that context and no direct record of what function object it came from, other than to trace backwards through the frames and bytecode as this hack is doing so crudely.  It's an interesting limitation, but it appears we're stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a class instead of a function and abusing the `__new__` method to make the class callable as a function?  Since the `__new__` method gets the class name as the first parameter, it can access all the class attributes

like in

```
class f(object):
        def __new__(cls, x):
            print cls.myattribute
            return x
```

this works as in

```
f.myattribute = "foo"
f(3)
foo
3
```

then you can do

```
g=f
f=None
g(3)
foo
3
```

The issue is that even if the object behaves like a function, it is not. Hence IDEs fail to provide you with the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is to define the function inside another function, and have the outer function return the inner one.  Then the inner function can access itself via a closure.  Here's a simple example:

```
def makeFunc():
    def f():
        return f._x
    return f
```

Then:

```
>>> f = makeFunc()
>>> f._x = "foo"
>>> f()
'foo'
>>> g = f
>>> del f
>>> g()
'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one method needed but you want a light-weight class with shared class state plus individual instance state, you might try the closure pattern like this:

```
# closure example of light weight object having class state,
#    local state, and single method
# This is a singleton in the sense that there is a single class
#    state (see Borg singleton pattern notebook)
#    BUT combined with local state
# As long as only one method is needed, this one way to do it
# If a full class singleton object is needed with multiple 
#    methods, best look at one of the singleton patterns

def LW_Object_Factory(localState):

    # class state - doesn't change
    lwof_args = (1, 2, 3)
    lwof_kwargs =  {'a': 4, 'b': 5}

    # local instance - function object - unique per
    # instantiation sharing class state
    def theObj(doc, x):
        print doc, 'instance:'
        print '\tinstance class state:\n\t\targs -', \
              lwof_args, ' kwargs -', lwof_kwargs
        print '\tinstance locals().items():'
        for i in locals().items():
            print '\t\t', i
        print '\tinstance argument x:\n\t\t', '"{}"'.format(x)
        print '\tinstance local state theObj.foo:\n\t\t',\
              '"{}"'.format(theObj.foo)
        print ''

    # setting local state from argument
    theObj.foo = localState

    return(theObj)

lwo1 = LW_Object_Factory('foo in local state for first')
lwo2 = LW_Object_Factory('foo in local state for second')

# prove each instance is unique while sharing class state
print 'lwo1 {} distinct instance from lwo2\n'\
      .format(id(lwo1) <> id(lwo2) and "IS" or "IS NOT")

# run them
lwo1('lwo1', 'argument lwo1') 
lwo2('lwo2', 'argument lwo2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy that is probably worse than the `func_defaults` idea, but is interesting nonetheless. It's hacky but I can't think of anything practically wrong with it.

We can implement a function that can refer to itself as a class with a single `__new__` method (the method that normally creates a new object of that class).

```
class new:
    """Returns True the first time an argument is passed, else False."""
    seen = set()
    def __new__(cls, x):
        old = x in cls.seen
        cls.seen.add(x)
        return not old

def main():
    print(new(1))  # True
    print(new(2))  # True
    print(new(2))  # false
    is_new = new
    print(is_new(1))  # False
```

Perhaps this pattern could be useful for a logging function...

```
class log_once:
    """Log a message if it has not already been logged.

    Args:
        msg: message to be logged
        printer: function to log the message
        id_: the identifier of the msg determines whether the msg
          has already been logged. Defaults to the msg itself.

    This is useful to log a condition that occurs many times in a single
    execution. It may be relevant that the condition was true once, but
    you did not need to know that it was true 10000 times, nor do you
    desire evidence to that effect to fill your terminal screen.
    """
    seen = set()
    def __new__(cls, msg, printer=print, id_=None):
        id_ = id_ or msg
        if id_ not in cls.seen:
            cls.seen.add(id_)
            printer(id_)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_once(1)
    log_once(1)
    log_once(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define your function inside a closure:

```
def generate_f():
    def f():
        return f.x
    return f

f = generate_f()

f.x = 314
g = f

del f
print g()
# => 314
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this alot.

```
from functools import update_wrapper

def dictAsGlobals(f):
    nf = type(f)(f.__code__, f.__dict__, f.__name__, f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)
    try: nf.__kwdefaults__ = f.__kwdefaults__
    except AttributeError: pass
    nf.__dict__ = f.__dict__
    nf.__builtins__ = f.__globals__["__builtins__"]
    return update_wrapper(nf, f)

@dictAsGlobals
def f():
    global timesCalled
    timesCalled += 1
    print(len.__doc__.split("\n")[0])
    return factor0 * factor1

vars(f).update(timesCalled = 0, factor0 = 3, factor1 = 2)

print(f())
print(f())
print(f.timesCalled)
```

Comment: Is this still correct? I tried it and now my function won't detect any imports.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply but I just stumbled upon this. I would have to argue that the way that “g” is asked to work is non-Pythonic. Inside function, the name “f“ refers to the value of a global variable at the time the function is called.  Given that, consider the following:

```
def f():
    print(f)
f, g = 42, f
g()  # prints 42
del f
g()  # raises an exception
```

Hopefully, no one argues that this is incorrect behavior. Given that fact, I cam only vote for any answer that requires the use of a different variable name (e.g. “self”) inside the function.

Comment: @mykhal: What you have asked for is contrary to the design of python. This explains why.