# Are you allowed to modify func_defaults (__defaults__ in Python 3.x) in Python?

Tags: python

I've tried doing this in Python 2.6, and it does "work":

```
>>> def f(i='I'): return i
...
>>> f.func_defaults = (10,)
>>> f()
10
```

But is this officially specified behavior, or am I hitting an implementation-specific behavior?

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean you should actually *do* it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) `func_defaults` is documented as "writable", so it would seem to be defined behavior.

Comment: Awesome! Docs also say this is new as of 2.4.

Comment: This seems to be respected in practice too: it works in IronPython 3.0.0, Jython 2.5.1+, and pypy-1.9.1.

Comment: @allyourcode: What's new in 2.4 is `func_name` being writable, not `func_defaults`.