# Python: Quick and dirty datatypes (DTO)

Tags: python, dto

Very often, I find myself coding trivial datatypes like

```py
class Pruefer:
    def __init__(self, ident, maxNum=float('inf'), name=""):
        self.ident  = ident
        self.maxNum = maxNum
        self.name   = name
```

While this is very useful (Clearly I don't want to replace the above with anonymous 3-tuples), it's also very boilerplate.

Now for example, when I want to use the class in a dict, I have to add more boilerplate like

```py
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.ident, self.maxNum, self.name)
```

I admit that it might be difficult to recognize a general pattern amongst all my boilerplate classes, but nevertheless I'd like to as this question:

- Are there any
  popular idioms in python to derive quick and dirty datatypes with named accessors?
- Or maybe if there are not, maybe a Python guru might want to show off some metaclass hacking or class factory to make my life easier?

Comment: I think `namedtuple` is good enough (added full answer with code example)

Comment: [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) now allows default values in 3.7+

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Pruefer = namedtuple("Pruefer", "ident maxNum name")
>>> pr = Pruefer(1,2,3)
>>> pr.ident
1
>>> pr.maxNum
2
>>> pr.name
3
>>> hash(pr)
2528502973977326415
```

To provide default values, you need to do little bit more... Simple solution is to write subclass with redefinition for `__new__` method:

```
>>> class Pruefer(namedtuple("Pruefer", "ident maxNum name")):
...     def __new__(cls, ident, maxNum=float('inf'), name=""):
...         return super(Pruefer, cls).__new__(cls, ident, maxNum, name)
... 
>>> Pruefer(1)
Pruefer(ident=1, maxNum=inf, name='')
```

Comment: That's very nice! Do you happen to also know something that allows me to have default values?

Comment: @JoSo -- You could just have a factory function which has defaults and returns a `Pruefer` instance.

Comment: This might be just me, but I would prefer `("ident","maxNum","name")` to the version with a whitespace separated string ... It seems a little more obvious to me what is going on.

Comment: @mgilson: The docs say that you can use `["a1","a2","a3"]`, too. (But I'm personally fine with the less-ink "a1 a2 a3". Just think `perl`'s `qw(a1 a2 a3)` ;>)

Comment: @JoSo Updated answer with default values definition.

Comment: @mgilson: Regarding factory: Obviously true, embarassed to have missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev -- I wouldn't have thought of getting to the default arguments that way.  Very clever.  (would +1 again if I could)

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev: Very very nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JoSo -- I prefer not to think of `perl`'s anything ... :-p ... I write python to stay away from `perl`.

Comment: @mgilson: I recently did some real-world text processing which is where perl really shines. It's quite a different language from python and clearly has its uses. It's great for readability to have all those implicit variables!

Comment: Another way to handle the defaults would be to use the `_replace()` method. e.g. `template = namedtuple("Pruefer", "ident maxNum name")(1, float('inf'), "")` and then you can do `template._replace(ident=2)` to get a new object `Pruefer(ident=2, maxNum=inf, name='')`

Comment: @Duncan -- I personally like to add the defaults after the fact:  `Pruefer.__new__.func_defaults=(1,float('inf'),"")`  (See my late answer)

Comment: Gives the error "TypeError: namedtuple() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Answer (score 14):

One of the most promising things from with Python 3.6 is variable annotations. They allow to define namedtuple as class in next way:

```
In [1]: from typing import NamedTuple

In [2]: class Pruefer(NamedTuple):
   ...:     ident: int
   ...:     max_num: int
   ...:     name: str
   ...:     

In [3]: Pruefer(1,4,"name")
Out[3]: Pruefer(ident=1, max_num=4, name='name')
```

It same as a namedtuple, but is saves annotations and allow to check type with some static type analyzer like mypy.

Update: 15.05.2018

Now, in Python 3.7 [dataclasses](https://hackernoon.com/a-brief-tour-of-python-3-7-data-classes-22ee5e046517) are present so this would preferable way of defining DTO, also for backwardcompatibility you could use [attrs](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) library.

Answer (score 8):

> Are there any popular idioms in python to derive quick ... datatypes with named accessors?

[Dataclases](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass).  They accomplish this exact need.

Some answers have mentioned dataclasses, but here is an example.

**Code**

```
import dataclasses as dc


@dc.dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Pruefer:
    ident : int
    maxnum : float = float("inf")
    name : str  = ""
```

**Demo**

```
pr = Pruefer(1, 2.0, "3")

pr
# Pruefer(ident=1, maxnum=2.0, name='3')

pr.ident
# 1

pr.maxnum
# 2.0

pr.name
# '3'

hash(pr)
# -5655986875063568239
```

---

**Details**

You get:

- pretty reprs
- default values
- hashing
- dotted attribute-access
- ... much more

You don't (directly) get:

- tuple unpacking (unlike namedtuple)

Here's a [guide](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/) on the details of dataclasses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to add to the already excellent answer by Alexey Kachayev -- However, one thing that *may* be useful is the following pattern:

```
Pruefer.__new__.func_defaults = (1,float('inf'),"")
```

This would allow you to create a factory function which returns a new named-tuple which can have default arguments:

```
def default_named_tuple(name,args,defaults=None):
    named_tuple = collections.namedtuple(name,args)
    if defaults is not None:
        named_tuple.__new__.func_defaults = defaults
    return named_tuple
```

This may seem like black magic -- It did to me at first, but it's all documented in the [Data Model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) and discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784840/are-you-allowed-to-modify-func-defaults-defaults-in-python-3-x-in-python).

In action:

```
>>> default_named_tuple("Pruefer", "ident maxNum name",(1,float('inf'),''))
<class '__main__.Pruefer'>
>>> Pruefer = default_named_tuple("Pruefer", "ident maxNum name",(1,float('inf'),''))
>>> Pruefer()
Pruefer(ident=1, maxNum=inf, name='')
>>> Pruefer(3)
Pruefer(ident=3, maxNum=inf, name='')
>>> Pruefer(3,10050)
Pruefer(ident=3, maxNum=10050, name='')
>>> Pruefer(3,10050,"cowhide")
Pruefer(ident=3, maxNum=10050, name='cowhide')
>>> Pruefer(maxNum=12)
Pruefer(ident=1, maxNum=12, name='')
```

And only specifying some of the arguments as defaults:

```
>>> Pruefer = default_named_tuple("Pruefer", "ident maxNum name",(float('inf'),''))
>>> Pruefer(maxNum=12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
>>> Pruefer(1,maxNum=12)
Pruefer(ident=1, maxNum=12, name='')
```

Note that as written, It's probably only safe to pass a `tuple` in as `defaults`.  However, you could easily get more fancy by ensuring you have a reasonable `tuple` object within the function.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach which might help you to make your boiler plate code a little more generic is the iteration over the (local) variable dicts. This enables you to put your variables in a list and the processing of these in a loop. E.g:

```
class Pruefer:
     def __init__(self, ident, maxNum=float('inf'), name=""):
         for n in "ident maxNum name".split():
             v = locals()[n]  # extract value from local variables
             setattr(self, n, v)  # set member variable

     def printMemberVars(self):
         print("Member variables are:")
         for k,v in vars(self).items():
             print("  {}: '{}'".format(k, v))


P = Pruefer("Id", 100, "John")
P.printMemberVars()
```

gives:

```
Member Variables are:
  ident: 'Id'
  maxNum: '100'
  name: 'John'
```

From the viewpoint of efficient resource usage, this approach is of course suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

if using Python 3.7 you can use  Data Classes; Data Classes can be thought of as "mutable namedtuples with defaults"

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/