# Referencing function attributes from inside the function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can do this:

```
def f(n):
    f.data = 3.14
    return n ** 2
f(10), f.data
```

Out[8]:

```
(100, 3.14)
```

My understanding is that in `f.data`, the name `f` binds to the function object in the outer scope. It looks a bit awkward, but `self` doesn't work:

```
def f(n):
    self.data = 3.14
    return n ** 2
f(10), f.data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Is there an equivalent of `self` for referencing function attributes from the inside?

Comment: Don't do this. If you need to store state across function invocations, use a class.

Comment: No. Besides, the whole thing looks like globals in disguise: why not just return an extra value?

Comment: `self` is just the conventional name for the first argument to an instance method, not a magic value the refers to its containing function. Your code is fragile, as your function could be bound to a name other than `f`, and `f` could change, leaving your function referring to something other than itself with the global name `f`.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109289/how-can-python-function-access-its-own-attributes