# How can I access a function's func_dict? Is there an equivalent of self for functions?

Tags: python, function, class-method

I can access a functions' func_dict easily if I write its name inside it:

```
def func(a):
    print('{} {}'.format(func.prefix, a))

func.prefix = 'something'
func(4)
```

Is there any way I can access `prefix` without having to write `func` again, similar to `self` in class methods?

Comment: Are you sure `func` should not be a method of a class instead?

Comment: Or perhaps `prefix` should be an argument with a default value?

Comment: Frankly, the best solution (that involves no cheating with nonsense like adding a defaulted `self` argument to a function) is to make a callable class, per the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109542/364696) on the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109289/how-can-python-function-access-its-own-attributes). You can even do additional tricks, like assigning the values at the class definition layer, then saying `func = func()`, which will replace the class definition with a single instance of the class (that has a `self` that can access the class variables).

Answer (score -1):

You just did it.

```
def func(a):
    print('{} {}'.format(func.prefix,a))
```

If you call it by itself without setting `prefix` you will get an `AttributeError` since prefix will not yet have been defined

By defining `func.prefix='something'`, now when you call `func(4)` you will get `something 4` as an output. And you can just keep redefining `func.prefix` and it will update the `Attribute` in `func`.

Unless there is something more to your question, you've done it correctly already.

Comment: No point in answering if there is nothing more to add.  I think the greater question here is how to access the namespace without using the name of the function, so that if `func()` is renamed all of the internal references will work without also having to be changed.

Comment: Jkdc is right, that was my point.